# Why does the complier state "Invalid Syntax" for my first line of calculations?

Tags: python

I have to use loop and simple code, I can not use functions. I get an error on my first line of calculations and I am not sure why?

```
  import random

  #Input
  winning_number = random.randint(10,100)
  guessed_number = int(input('Enter your lottery pick (2 digits) or -999 to quit:')

  #Calculations
  first_winning_number = winning_number // 10
  second_winning_number = winning_number % 10
  first_guessed_number = guessed_number // 10
  second_guessed_number = guessed_number % 10

  #If Statements
  while guessed_number != -999:
      if guessed_number == winning_number:
          print('Exact Match: You win $10,000')
      if first_guessed_number == second_winning_number and second_guessed_number == first_winning_number:
          print('Match all digits: You win $3,000')
      if first_guessed_digit == second_winning_digit:
          print('Match one digit: You win $1,000')
      if first_guessed_digit == first_winning_digit:
          print('Match one digit: You win $1,000')
      if second_guessed_digit == second_winning_digit:
          print('Match one digit: You win $1,000')
      if second_guessed_digit == first_winning_digit:
          print('Match one digit: You win $1,000')
      else:
          print(guessed_number)
```

Comment: If your complier doesn't comply with your syntax, it shouldn't be called a complier :-P

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, if you get a mysterious error like that look at the previous line containing code. It's usually missing a `)`. It's easy for this to happen, many ides swallow extra closing parens.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the second parenthesis on your 3rd line.

Its
`guessed_number = int(input('Enter your lottery pick (2 digits) or -999 to quit:'))`

not
`guessed_number = int(input('Enter your lottery pick (2 digits) or -999 to quit:')`